What’s the best way to ensure player hand privacy in a Solana card game DApp?
I'm working on a Solana DApp for a card game where protecting player hand privacy is essential. I've come across Multi-Party Computation (MPC) and Zero-Knowledge Proofs (ZKP) as potential solutions. Has anyone implemented these (or other) methods for similar use cases? I’d love to hear about your experiences and any advice on which method might be best for a game like this.
